# Django-plolty-dash errors: for ImportError: Can't import 'Dash' from 'dash'

Tags: django, installation, importerror

```
Python version: 3.7.9
Django version: 3.1.1
django_plotly_dash: 1.4.2
```

I have tried to install `django_plotly_dash` package after I tested the Django project could work properly. That is to say, the development server works fine and the webpage can be opened without problems. However, after I install the `django_plotly_dash` package and add the following to the project settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    ...
    ]
```

Immediately, I had an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dash' from 'dash' (project\app\__init__.py)
```

Comment: So what does the code do that tries to use `Dash`? You've not included your actual use of the code in the error

Comment: I think it is nothing.

Comment: To be clear, my Django works fine when I installed the Dash_plotly_dash package. And I then just added the  'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig', to the settings of Django app. Then I have the Improt Error. The erro massage stated it is the Djangoproject\app\__init__.py cant import it.

Comment: but the file is actually empty. Additionally, when I tried to makemigrations, the same ImportError is repoted.

I hope this clarify the question a little bit.

Comment: The traceback started:

C:\Users\Buffalo\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\threading.py". line 926, in _bootstap_inner self.run()

Comment: Ok, so dash is a requirement of django_plotly_dash so are the requirements of that package installed?

Comment: yes, the django_plotly_dash and the requirement was installed. I am thinking if it is because of the Anaconda3 was installed long time ago even it meets the dash_plotly_dash requirement.

Comment: solved. I mistakenly named my own app as dash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but have now solved it.

What you should do is go to your ***urls.py*** file (the one that sits in the app you created) and add the following line:

```
from [FOLDER/S].[FOLDER/S].[NAME OF .PY FILE] import app
```

The ***[FOLDER/S]*** because you're leading it to the location of your py file where your Django/Plotly sits, and the ***import app*** because in your Django/Plotly py file you are creating `app = DjangoDash([name in str])`